# Why can't I get logwatch to output anything in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, logwatch

So I installed `logwatch` using [this](https://library.linode.com/server-monitoring/logwatch/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin) guide on a Ubuntu 12.04 box. I also setup `postfix` and my initial intention was to add a daily cronjob to email me these reports (I have the same setup on a Debian Wheezy box and it works just fine).

But somehow I can't get `logwatch` to actually output anything. No email is sent. To verify the `logwatch` output itself I ran

```
$logwatch --output stdout --format text
```

but that didn't output anything to the terminal. If I do the same command on the Debian box it outputs the report just as I would expect.

How can I debug why `logwatch` isn't running? Nothing seems to be captured in the logs either.

Comment: Could you run it with a sudo, please.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I get all this running as a superuser.